# Should I install UII for developing plugins from Package Manager Console or MS site?

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2013, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I want to install the UII to connect to and develop plugins in my organization. However, I can't decide between installing it using the package manager console (as discussed in [some nice blog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.UII.CommonAssemblies/)) or using the [download site from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44567).

Both feel right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that both are correct sources for the current UII DLLs.

The choice of which to use is a question of your development methods.

There are pros and cons to each but Stackoverflow is not the appropriate place to debate opinions per the rules.

Comment: That's a bit unexpected. The one installs the packages per solution, right? The other for the whole VS. Or so I thought... I was under the impression that one can't even install the Git package unless a solution is opened. Are you entirely certain that it's the same end result that we achieve independent of the approach?

Comment: No, NuGet (NOT Git) is a per project install - you can specify the project(s) to which you want to install the nuget package. With the DLLs from the SDK you specify via Add Reference (same as always.) The end result in all cases is a reference to the applicable DLLs in the specified projects.